# The graphics on my form move when I use the scrollbar

Tags: c#, forms, scrollbar, point

I am kind of new here but I will try to explain my problem as clearly as possible.
I am placing red dots on a form with a vertical and an horizontal scroll bar, if I place a dot at `(50,590)` and scroll to the right the dot "follows" the movement.

I am still unable to post images but I can post the link to them, the first picture is the dot in its original position, the second picture is the dot after i scroll to the right
[dot original position](http://i49.tinypic.com/24y4kxt.png), 
[dot after scrolling](http://i46.tinypic.com/17vdj6.png)

I want the dots to keep their original position when I scroll, actually I can' t understand while they do not already do it.

This is the code

```
Bitmap MyBitmap = new Bitmap(3000,3000);

Graphics MyGraphicObject;

Brush red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     MyGraphicObject = e.Graphics;
     MyGraphicObject.DrawImage(MyBitmap, 0, 0, MyBitmap.Width, MyBitmap.Height);
     MyGraphicObject.Dispose(); 
}

private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     MyGraphicObject = Graphics.FromImage(MyBitmap);
     MyGraphicObject.FillRectangle(red, e.X-2, e.Y-2, 4, 4);
}
```

can you please help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: are you drawing into a picturebox or into the form? form has issues with redrawing afaik, try pulling another window above the form and away again, does this solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i am drawing directly into the form. MOving a window over the form doesn' t help because my graphic is persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a built-in Windows setting named "Show window contents while dragging", it is turned on by default on all modern version of Windows.  What that does is make Windows automatically move the content of a window that has scrollbars when you scroll.  And only generates a paint request for the part of the window that was not previously visible.

This is what makes it *look* like your bitmap is moving.  You'll need to fix it by forcing the entire window to be repainted, not just part of it.  Paste this code into your form class:

```
    protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se) {
        base.OnScroll(se);
        this.Invalidate(false);
    }
```

This will fix your problem, your bitmap now repaints in the same position.  However, not without seeing the artifact from the Windows setting, for a split second you'll see the bitmap in the scrolled position.  The visual effect is similar to seeing your bitmap doing the pogo.  No fix for that, double-buffering can't fix it and you cannot reasonably turn off that setting.

Btw, do fix the bug in your code, you should *not* dispose the graphics object.  You didn't create it.  This will cause trouble in the future when you start tinkering with double-buffering.  Delete that statement.